# when I pull some image I get "Download failed: unknown blob"

Tags: docker

sudo docker pull nginx
I get error in log

sudo journalctl -u docker.service

```
16:33:44 ighack-PC dockerd[6331]: time="2020-06-26T16:33:44.124208457+08:00" level=error msg="Download failed: unknown blob"
6月 26 16:33:44 ighack-PC dockerd[6331]: time="2020-06-26T16:33:44.124475427+08:00" level=info msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: unknown blob"
6月 26 16:34:25 ighack-PC dockerd[6331]: time="2020-06-26T16:34:25.926062953+08:00" level=error msg="Not continuing with pull after error: error pulling image configuration: Get h
```

/etc/docker/daemon.json

```
{
    "data-root":"/home/ighack/Documents/docker",
    "registry-mirrors":["https://hub-mirror.c.163.com"],
    "log-level": "info"
}
```

I have change so many source,
I have reinstall docker

Docker version 19.03.12, build 48a66213fe

debain 10 (deepin v20 bate)

Comment: Did you tried to rename your daemon.json and run again?

Comment: Try to remove the registry mirror

Comment: if I remove registry mirror I get error "pulling image configuration: Get https://production.cloudflare.docker.com/regist …………………… timeout"

Comment: I change network.but sometime is ok,sometime is not